# "identifier "hInstance" is undefined" and "too few arguments in function call"

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-errors, scope, arguments

I'm trying to make a window with C++, but it's giving me this error.

```cpp
    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
        L"Window",
        style,
        rect.top,
        rect.right - rect.left,
        rect.bottom - rect.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance, // first error line is here
        NULL
    ); // second error line is here
```

The first error line tells me `identifier "hInstance" is undefined` while I used it multiple times before and it didn't give me an error, and the second one tells me `too few arguments in function call`.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: The error is correct given the current code. You did not declare a variable called `hInstance` in the code that you show.

Comment: The places where you used `hInstance` "before" are probably in a different scope from where you are trying to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects 12 arguments instead of 11. It seems you forgot to specify the argument

```
rect.left,
```

paired with the argument

```
rect.top,
```

As for the second error then you should check whether the declaration of `hInstance` is visible in the point of the function call.

Instead of `hInstance` you could use the expression `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.

Comment: "*Instead of hInstance you could use the expression `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`*" - unless this code is in a DLL, then you can't. You have to use the handle of the module that owns the code. In a DLL, register and create your window classes using the module handle provided to your `DllMain()`/`DllEntryPoint()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You mean "Unless this code is in an **EXE**, then you can't."

Comment: @RaymondChen no, I meant what I said: "*Use [`GetModuleHandle(NULL)`] ... UNLESS the code is inside a DLL, then [use the `DllMain` parameter instead].*" Calling `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` inside a **DLL** gets the module handle of the **EXE** that the DLL is loaded in, which is the wrong handle to use when registering and creating window classes from inside the DLL. You yourself [wrote about that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873).

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah, now I see. Your reply was ambiguous. I parsed it as a response to the previous sentence: "Unless you are in a DLL, you can't use GMH(NULL)."   But you intended it to be parsed as a *continuation* of the previous sentence: "You can use GMH(NULL), unless you in a DLL, in which case you can't."

Comment: @RaymondChen yup, exactly